# Facebook not showing any posts

Tags: facebook

Why does this happen? This happens on all browsers but not on my phone.[image]

Comment: What addons are you using? Is this for all pages or just the Veritasium page? Is your internet speed sufficient (i.e. is the problem just a slow internet connection)? Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: This is not really an answer, because it's only anecdotal, but sometimes you have logged in somewhere else and a token has gotten stale.  Check out "Where you are logged in" under the Security and Login section on the settings page.